# How to get size of PlaneGeometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made mesh with PlanGeometry and BasicMaterial.

```
function createMesh(width, height) {
      let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height);
      let mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color: 0xffffff,
          transparent: true,
          side: THREE.DoubleSide,
          opacity: 0.5
      });
      return new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat);
  }
```

And I used this mesh in other place and make transformed this mesh.
So

```
mesh.matrix.identify();
mesh.applyMatrix(matrix); // make some transform.
```

Now, I want to get size of plane geometry
So I tried with following method.

```
  let boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);
  let size = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
  size = boundingBox.getSize(size);
  console.log('size', size);
```

But size is not correct.
How can I get width, height value when created PlaneGeometry (width, height) before?

```
let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height);
```

I want to know width, height value upper code.
Please anyone help.

Comment: `mesh.geometry.parameters` - take a look at this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have better results by checking the bounding box, `geometry.parameters` is not a reliable object - it's only created for primitives, and is not updated when the object is manipulated, so it won't reflect any scale changes.

```
mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox()
const size = mesh.geometry.boundingBox.getSize()
console.log('size', size);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a answer.

```
let parameters = mesh.geometry.parameters;
let size = {
    width: parameters.width,
    height: parameters.height
};
console.log('size', size);
```

Thanks @prisoner849.